# Two onclicks are fired causing fragment transaction to cause error

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

**What is currently happening**

1. I have 2 entities(linear layouts) in the adapter that on click of it
   makes a fragment transaction to a new fragment
2. Both of the elements leads to new fragment
3. its working fine if i click one liner layout. but when i am doing
   testing, i noticed that by mistake if i click both of them(since a
   row has two on click that leads to same fragment ) two commit cannot
   work as the error suggests
4. is there somehow i can resolve this keeping my architecture intact

---

**AdptHome.java**

```
public class AdptHome extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listData;
    Context context;
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    public AdptHome(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _listData, Context _context, FragmentTransaction _ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        listData=_listData;
        context=_context;
        ft=_ft;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View retval;
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=listData.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        retval = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_home_list, null);

        final TextView titleLeftId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleLeftId);
        final ImageView imageLeftId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageLeftId);
        final TextView categoryLeftId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryLeftId);


        final TextView titleRightId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleRightId);
        final ImageView imageRightId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageRightId);
        final TextView categoryRightId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryRightId);

        final LinearLayout layoutLeftId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutLeftId);
        final LinearLayout layoutRightId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutRightId);

        String[] imageSplitted = mapData.get("imagename").split("~");
        String[] idSplitted = mapData.get("id").split("~");
        String[] nameSplitted = mapData.get("name").split("~");

        //First image
        String uri1 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[0];
        int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);


        //Second image
        String uri2 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[1];
        int imageResource2 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri2, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource2);

        imageLeftId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleLeftId.setText(nameSplitted[0]);
        categoryLeftId.setText(idSplitted[0]);


        imageRightId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleRightId.setText(nameSplitted[1]);
        categoryRightId.setText(idSplitted[1]);



        layoutLeftId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleLeftId.getText().toString());  
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
                //Set the categoryId in the application class
                AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryLeftId.getText().toString()));
            }
        });


        layoutRightId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Changing a fragment from within a displayed fragment to a new fragment
                FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleRightId.getText().toString());  
                //ft.hide(FrgHome.this);
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();

                //Set the categoryId in the application class
                AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryRightId.getText().toString()));
            }
        });



        return retval;
    }

}
```

**adpt_home_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLeftId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLeftId"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleLeftId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryLeftId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_just_a_line" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_just_a_line" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutRightId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRightId"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleRightId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryRightId"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_just_a_line" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_just_a_line" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Log:**

```
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): Process: com.windhyaworks, PID: 26031
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031): java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:583)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.windhyaworks.adapters.AdptHome$1.onClick(AdptHome.java:106)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-25 11:23:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(26031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### {EDIT}

```
public class AdptHome extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listData;
    Context context;
    FragmentManager fm;

    public AdptHome(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _listData,
            Context _context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        listData = _listData;
        context = _context;
        fm = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View retval;
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=listData.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        retval = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_home_list, null);

        final TextView titleLeftId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleLeftId);
        final ImageView imageLeftId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageLeftId);
        final TextView categoryLeftId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryLeftId);


        final TextView titleRightId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleRightId);
        final ImageView imageRightId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageRightId);
        final TextView categoryRightId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryRightId);

        final LinearLayout layoutLeftId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutLeftId);
        final LinearLayout layoutRightId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutRightId);

        String[] imageSplitted = mapData.get("imagename").split("~");
        String[] idSplitted = mapData.get("id").split("~");
        String[] nameSplitted = mapData.get("name").split("~");

        //First image
        String uri1 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[0];
        int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);


        //Second image
        String uri2 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[1];
        int imageResource2 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri2, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource2);

        imageLeftId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleLeftId.setText(nameSplitted[0]);
        categoryLeftId.setText(idSplitted[0]);


        imageRightId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleRightId.setText(nameSplitted[1]);
        categoryRightId.setText(idSplitted[1]);



        layoutLeftId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleLeftId.getText().toString());  
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
                //Set the categoryId in the application class
                AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryLeftId.getText().toString()));
            }
        });


        layoutRightId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Changing a fragment from within a displayed fragment to a new fragment
                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

                FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleRightId.getText().toString());  
                //ft.hide(FrgHome.this);
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();

                //Set the categoryId in the application class
                AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryRightId.getText().toString()));
            }
        });



        return retval;
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100): Process: com.windhyaworks, PID: 29100
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #349: Error inflating class fragment
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at com.windhyaworks.fragments.FrgAddNewJobs.onCreateView(FrgAddNewJobs.java:129)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #349: Duplicate id 0x7f0c001a, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0c0019 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4808)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
12-25 11:58:04.977: E/AndroidRuntime(29100):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont create fragment transaction globally. For each and every time you have to create new fragment transaction.

Comment: but is it possible to create a fragment transaction in adapter ? .... because i had passed it from activity .... can fragment transaction be created in adapter directely ?

Comment: @Devrath then pass fragment manager to adapter by using constructor. From manager u can get transaction.

Comment: That is problm with you fragment layout i guess.

Comment: Yes indeed .... its because of fragment layout but, since i have a requirement not to change the architecture is to use a session flag .... i have shared my solution .... [+1] for the info you gave

Answer (score 0):

### Sharing my solution::

Actually problem was created because i had two items in adapter, getting around this is to set a session variable. It might not be fesable but it is a good way to get around the problem since it is used in many places

---

```
public class AdptHome extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listData;
    Context context;
    FragmentManager fm;

    public AdptHome(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _listData,
            Context _context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        listData = _listData;
        context = _context;
        fm = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View retval;
        HashMap<String, String> mapData=listData.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        retval = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_home_list, null);

        final TextView titleLeftId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleLeftId);
        final ImageView imageLeftId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageLeftId);
        final TextView categoryLeftId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryLeftId);


        final TextView titleRightId = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.titleRightId);
        final ImageView imageRightId=(ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.imageRightId);
        final TextView categoryRightId=(TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.categoryRightId);

        final LinearLayout layoutLeftId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutLeftId);
        final LinearLayout layoutRightId=(LinearLayout) retval.findViewById(R.id.layoutRightId);

        String[] imageSplitted = mapData.get("imagename").split("~");
        String[] idSplitted = mapData.get("id").split("~");
        String[] nameSplitted = mapData.get("name").split("~");

        //First image
        String uri1 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[0];
        int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);


        //Second image
        String uri2 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[1];
        int imageResource2 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri2, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Drawable res2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource2);

        imageLeftId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleLeftId.setText(nameSplitted[0]);
        categoryLeftId.setText(idSplitted[0]);


        imageRightId.setImageDrawable(res1);
        titleRightId.setText(nameSplitted[1]);
        categoryRightId.setText(idSplitted[1]);



        layoutLeftId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(AppController.isHorizontalListTransaction()==false){

                    AppController.setHorizontalListTransaction(true);

                    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                    FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleLeftId.getText().toString());  
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
                    //Set the categoryId in the application class
                    AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryLeftId.getText().toString()));
                }
            }
        });


        layoutRightId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(AppController.isHorizontalListTransaction()==false){

                    AppController.setHorizontalListTransaction(true);
                    //Changing a fragment from within a displayed fragment to a new fragment
                    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

                    FrgAddNewJobs fragment2 = FrgAddNewJobs.newInstance(titleRightId.getText().toString());  
                    //ft.hide(FrgHome.this);
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2, FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgAddNewJobs.class.getSimpleName()).commit();

                    //Set the categoryId in the application class
                    AppController.setCategoryId(Integer.valueOf(categoryRightId.getText().toString()));
                }
            }
        });     

        return retval;
    }
}
```

***note:: AppController is the session variable***
Also you have to set the flag in the class where onclick takes you .... simple flag convention